# c# Windows Forms Application Exception not thrown!

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a strange problem, will appreciate if anyone can help.

I have the following function:

```
void Foo()
{
    MessageBox.Show("here");
    throw new Exception();
}
```

I call it in the following two cases (separately - not at the same time):

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Case 1
     Foo();
}

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Case 2
    Foo();
}
```

I can see the messagebox (I receive message "here") in both case but:

[Case 1] The application doesn't break on the exception (in Debug mode) and remains silent!

[Case 2] Application correctly breaks and I can see that there is an exception in the Foo().

Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, i'll add it to the question

Comment: So, do you see message box on programm start up in `case 1`?

Comment: yes, as I said: I receive message "here" in both case

Comment: Start from enabling exceptions in Visual Studio: Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions and see whether it will appear in Debug mode

Comment: If you surround the calls to foo() with a try/catch block what happens in the case that currently stays "silent"?

Comment: @dlev: The exception is caught in try/catch but but even from there can not be thrown;

Comment: @valipour that makes perfect sense. I'm pretty sure Kragen's explanation is right (i.e. that the message loop is eating your exception before you get to see it.)

Comment: @sll: Excelent! it works, please add it as answer so I can accept your answer. But now the question is why?! Why it works in Case2 but not Case1?

Comment: @valipour, are you sure that my comment could be accepted as an answer? I've just helped you a bit with debugging not a whole issue

Comment: @ssl, donna but that was a perfect point! thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that the call to the constructor looks a bit like this:

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
Application.Run(form);
```

The crucial part being that you are calling the constuctor of `Form2` directly wheras it is the application class / message pump that is calling `Form2_Load`.

The final piece of the puzzle is that exceptions thrown inside a Win32 message pump are handled differently (to start with see the [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) ) - what you may also find confusing is that exceptions are also handled differently based on whether the project is build in the Debug configuration or not.

You might have a handler for the [Application.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.unhandledexception%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) - this would explain the behaviour you have described.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Application.ThreadException +=
            (o, args) =>
                {
                    // Case 1
                    MessageBox.Show(args.Exception.ToString());
                };

        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Case 2
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: But the goal is to get the exception on the line not to catch it.

Comment: Your constructor is throwing exception - you can catch it either in constructor, or outside. You throwing exception on the UI thread - someone has to catch it - default "Exception happened" window or your handler.

Comment: Again I should say the problem is not catching the exception, the problem is (was) that visual studio weren't showing exception when it happened.